# Запросы к API. Почему они работают так?

Tags: api, requests, cors, response

Есть Api сервис Кладр. Проблема в том, что обращаясь через поисковую строку браузера к api, я получаю в ответ json. Но при обращении из скрипта подключенного на странице сайта, через fetch. Я получаю ошибку CORS.

> Access to fetch at
>   'http://kladr-api.ru/api.php?query=%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81&contentType=city&limit=2&withParent=0'
>   from origin 'http://mysite.ru' has been blocked by CORS policy.

При обращении из node js я так же получаю ответ. Причем у меня есть несколько доменов и на всех такая ошибка. Я могу получить json везде, но не напрямую из скрипта подключенного к странце. Почему я не могу получить get-запросом данные с открытого api? В чем причина такого поведения?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) почитате [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score -1):

Используйте официальный jQuery плагин КЛАДР: https://github.com/fias-api/jquery

```js
$(function(){
  $.kladr.api({
    query: 'Крас',
    type: 'city',
    limit: 2,
    withParent: 0
  }, function(r){ console.log(r);})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fias-api/jquery@2.2.2/jquery.kladr.min.js"></script>
```